# create multiple hidden input objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create hidden input fields in a form that pass latitude and longitude variables to `$_POST` variables but keep getting "undefined" returned.

I am using the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostition` method.

Anyone know why the variables `locationLat` and `locationLon` return undefined?

```
$(document).ready (function () {

var locationMessage, locationLat, locationLon;

var inputLat = document.createElement("input");
inputLat.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
inputLat.setAttribute("name", "inputLat");
inputLat.setAttribute("id", "inputLatitude");

var inputLon = document.createElement("input");
inputLon.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
inputLon.setAttribute("name", "inputLon");
inputLon.setAttribute("id", "inputLongitude");

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
        function (position) {
        // set value for location data
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        locationLat = latitude;
        locationLon = longitude;

        inputLat.setAttribute("value", locationLat);
        inputLon.setAttribute("value", locationLon);
},

function (error) {
    var errorTypes = {
      0: "Unknown error",
      1: "Permission denied by user",
      2: "Position is not available",
      3: "Request timed out"
    };

    var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];

    if (error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
      errorMessage += (": " + error.message);
    }

    locationMessage = errorMessage;
    // if error set value for location data 

    inputLat.setAttribute("value", locationMessage);
    inputLon.setAttribute("value", locationMessage);

  });
} 


document.getElementById("series").appendChild(inputLat);  
document.getElementById("series").appendChild(inputLon);

});
```

Comment: Are you checking the values of `locationLat` and `locationLon` before or after the user gives permission to share their location data? Requestiong location data is an asynchronous operation.